# spark data frame collect_set flatmap

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame which maps to a case class like below.

```
case class Data(key :String, tokens : List[String], anothercol : String)
```

I would like to get distinct tokens grouped by key. If tokens is not list I could do:

```
dataDF.groupBy($"key").agg(collect_set($"tokens"))
```

and I would get distinct but with List how would I do that ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion would be to use [Lateral explode](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView) as in Hive. The idea is to create one row from each element in the tokens List. Then you can use the agg and collect_set.

you can write an sql to achieve this